# regular expression alphabet and numbers without space in android

Tags: android, regex, validation

I want a regular expression for user_id. Following restrictions:

- It should start with `a-z` or `A-Z`
- It should not start with `0-9`
- No space in string (user_ID)
- length must be between 6 and 15
- These characters not allowed `(*/!@#$%^&*()_+)`
- only alphabets and numbers allowed.

Example:

```
(4abcdef==false)(abc4dfr==true)(abcd 4715==false)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read a [description or regular expressions in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)? People here are glad to help if you have a problem with your code, but won't normally write code for you from scratch. Hint: read about character classes and quantifiers, it must immediately suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,14}
```

The first block `[a-zA-Z]` makes an alphabet mandatory at the beginning, the second block `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,14}` takes minimum 5 and upto 14 characters long. So including the first character makes it 6 to 15 characters long.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suspect you meant `a-zA-Z`, not `a-ZA-Z`.

Comment: Yup! Thank you. Corrected It.